# Create JSON file from multiple txt files

Tags: javascript, json, bash, jq

I have the following problem:

*I want a JSON files with the keys, {"key1","key2"} each having several values and are written in a txt file. The txt file for each key looks like this:

```
key1.txt:
val1
val2
val3
..
```

and similar structure for key2.txt. Using these I want to create a json file that has the following structure:

```
{
    key1:
    [ "val1"
      "val2"
       ...
    ]

    key2:
    [ "val1"
      "val2"
       ...
    ]
}
```

I hope the question is clear. I prefer using bash to do this, if possible.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? share your code, or are you expecting code from scratch?

Comment: Question isn't clear, this looks more like a spec and there is no *question* asked or attempt to solve problem shown in what you posted

Comment: I apologize for the question. I realized how simple the task was and that it did not warrant a post here. Sorry! I will close the post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update a json file by the contents read from other files using jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74055447/how-to-update-a-json-file-by-the-contents-read-from-other-files-using-jq)

Answer (score 0):

Try below one

```
#!/bin/bash
json="{"
for f in <path of directory>/*.txt
do
filename=$(basename "$f")
filename="${filename%.*}"  
json=$json'"'$filename'"'": ["
while IFS= read -r line; do
echo $filename
json=$json'"'$line'",'
done < $f  
json="${json%?}"
json=$json"],"
done
json="${json%?}"
json=$json"}"
echo $json
```

Answer (score 0):

jq can be used to read in multiple files using the `--slurpfile` option.  The files however *must* be an actual json file.  Since your files aren't in a json format, you need to convert them.

```
$ jq -R '.' key1.txt > /tmp/key1.json && \
  jq -R '.' key2.txt > /tmp/key2.json && \
  jq --slurpfile key1 /tmp/key1.json \
     --slurpfile key2 /tmp/key2.json \
     -n '{ key1: $key1, key2: $key2 }'
```

Otherwise, if you don't want to deal with temporary files, you could use a subshell to create the json arrays and pass them in using `--argjson`.

```
$ jq --argjson key1 "$(jq -R '.' key1.txt | jq -s '.')" \
     --argjson key2 "$(jq -R '.' key2.txt | jq -s '.')" \
     -n '{ key1: $key1, key2: $key2 }'
```

Comment: Please note that the -R option allows jq to read non-JSON files.

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop to build an array of entries and then merge the loop output with a final jq invocation.

```bash
for f in *.txt; do
  <"$f" jq -nR --arg key "${f%.txt}" '{$key,value:[inputs]}';
done | jq -s 'from_entries'
```

Note that this question&answer is very similar to [How to update a json file by the contents read from other files using jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74055447/how-to-update-a-json-file-by-the-contents-read-from-other-files-using-jq/74056106) and [Construct json through jq tool in shell script loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74095381/construct-json-through-jq-tool-in-shell-script-loop/74095461).