# Construct json through jq tool in shell script loop

Tags: json, shell, jq

json can be created using the following command.

```
  jq -n \
  --arg v1 "Value1" \
  --arg v2 "Value2" \
  '{k1: "$v1", k2:$v2'}
```

But when my key is mutable, how should I loop? For example, the script I execute is

```
test.sh k1=v1 k2=v2 k3=v3
```

test.sh is as follows

```
index=1
while ((index <= "$#")); do
  data_i_key=$(echo ${!index} | awk -F "=" '{print $1}')
  data_i_value=$(echo ${!index} | awk -F "=" '{print $2}')
  let index++
  JSON_STRING=$(jq -n \
    --arg value "$data_i_value" \
    '{'"$data_i_key"': $value'})
    echo $JSON_STRING
```

The above print result is

```
{ "K3": "V3" }
```

if I replace it with

```
JSON_STRING+=$(jq -n \
    --arg val_value "$dataValue" \
    '{'"$data_i_key"': $val_value'})
```

The print result is

```
{ "k1": "v1" }{ "k2": "v2" }{ "K3": "V3" }
```

The above two methods have not achieved the goal, do you have a good way to deal with it? My desired output is

{ "k1": "v1" , "k2": "v2" ,"K3": "V3" }

hope you can help me.

Comment: How does the script decide when to upper-case key and value? k1, v1, k2, v2 are inserted verbatim into the JSON, but k3 and v3 are uppercased to K3 and V3. Intentional or typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest a totally different, but simpler, approach:

```bash
for kv; do
  echo "$kv" | jq -R './"=" | {key:first,value:last}'
done | jq -s 'from_entries'
```

It builds `{key: …, value: …}` objects from your positional parameters (splitting them by the equal sign) and then slurping all those objects in a second `jq` process, converting them into a single object via [`from_entries`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#to_entries,from_entries,with_entries).

Alternatively, using `-n` (`--null-input`), `--args` and then accessing via `$ARGS.positional`. This avoids the loop and the second `jq` call altogether.

```
jq -n '$ARGS.positional | map(./"=" | {key:first,value:last}) | from_entries' --args "$@"
```

If your values can contain `=` themselves, you have to join all but the first value of the array:

```
jq -n '$ARGS.positional
| map(./"=" | {key:first,value:.[1:]|join("=")})
| from_entries' --args "$@"
```

Comment: Going further: `jq -n --args '$ARGS.positional | map(. / "=" | {key:first, value:last}) | from_entries' k1=v1 k2=v2 k
3=v3` (or `… "$@"`)

Comment: @pmf you are too fast, I was already extending my answer :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but I don't quite understand how $ARGS.positional is used? If I only want to construct json from the second parameter, how should I modify it?

Comment: @junhu what do you mean with "only json from the second parameter?"

Comment: Still the above example, my result would be {  "k2": "v2" ,"K3": "V3" }

Comment: @junhu I'm not sure I understand. The Q asks for an object with 3 properties (all of which are extracted from the positional parameters of the script. But `$ARGS.positional` is an array, so you can easily slice it, e.g. `[1:]`

Comment: @junhu Maybe slicing on bash's side using `"${@:2}"` is what you are looking for.

Comment: Or, avoiding the need for `from_entries` => `echo k1=v1 k2=v2 k3=v3 | jq -R './" " | map(./"=" | {(first): last}) | add'`

Comment: @glennjackman yes, that will work too. But it's not really any shorter nor clearer than using `from_entries` – you still need to build the objects (`{…}`) and then merge them (`|add`). Compare that to build key-value pairs (`{…}`) and then converting to object (`|from_entries`).

Comment: The main difference is one jq invocation versus launching jq N+1 times.

Comment: @glennjackman ah, I see, in the first version. Yes, but the second version only invokes `jq` once. Splitting on blanks and then `=` will fail for values (or keys) containing blanks.

Comment: yes, but also for values containing `=`

Answer (score 0):

Use parentheses around the key expression to have it evaluated:

```bash
jq -n --arg k1 "Key1" --arg v1 "Value1" '{($k1): $v1}'
```

```json
{
  "Key1": "Value1"
}
```

Comment: I know this method, but now I want to write all the parameters together in json format in the loop and assign them to JSON_STRING。

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this, which will handle an arbitrary number of key=value arguments:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

args=()
for arg; do
    IFS="=" read -r k v <<<"$arg"
    args+=("$k" "$v")
done

jq -n --args '
    $ARGS.positional as $a
    | reduce range(0; $a | length; 2) as $i ({}; .[$a[$i]] = $a[$i + 1])
' "${args[@]}"
```

Produces:

```bash
$ ./test.sh k1=v1 k2=v2 k3=v3
{
  "k1": "v1",
  "k2": "v2",
  "k3": "v3"
}
```